# When downloading the blockchain my application is become unusable, is there an issue with my code or am I using the BitcoinJ library incorrectly?

Tags: bitcoinj, android

I am building a Bitcoin wallet with the BitcoinJ Library, after looking at the example of fetching a transaction that they have shown on their [github](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/FetchTransactions.java) it shows that you need to download the blockchain however.

When attempting to download the blockchain to view the balance of my wallet, it begins to lock up and become unusable. I have even tried downloading the blockchain in an async task like so, but still the app becomes completely unusable and the UI doesn't even load. What am I missing? I thought that the download wouldn't be that large as I am attempting to create an SPV wallet which from what I understand doesn't download the entire blockchain, or is this something I need to configure seperately?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         DownloadBlockchain().execute()
    }

    inner class DownloadBlockchain : AsyncTask<Void, Int, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): String {
            Globals.peerGroup?.startAsync()
            Globals.peerGroup?.downloadBlockChain()
            return "complete"
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Globals.peerGroup?.stopAsync()
            Globals.wallet?.saveToFile(Globals.walletFile)
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `downloadBlockChain()` method looks like it downloads the whole blockchain. It looks like the `PeerGroup.setFastCatchupTime` method might be helpful to prevent it from downloading full blocks before that time. I imagine you'll use a method or change a boolean value to only download block headers for your SPV wallet, but I don't know where that would be.

https://bitcoinj.github.io/speeding-up-chain-sync may be a useful reference.